# Why CXProvider's providerDidReset invoked?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, voip, callkit

We integrated CallKit for audio/video calling features.

Recently, few production users reported that the system prompts a `Call Failed` alert during a call. This is happening on a device running iOS 16.1, and it happens very frequently.

`CXProvider` setup

```
let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: appName()! )
providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = true
providerConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
providerConfiguration.maximumCallGroups = 1
providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber, .generic]
providerConfiguration.iconTemplateImageData = UIImage.callKitIcon?.pngData()
providerConfiguration.includesCallsInRecents = false

callProvider = CXProvider(configuration: providerConfiguration)
callProvider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
```

We investigated the device logs and found that CXProvider's `providerDidReset(_:)` callback was invoked.
Apple developer documentation explains this func called when the provider is reset. We could not understand the reason behind this failure.

I would like to know more about this callback, in which situation the provider reset.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Call Failed Prompt]

Comment: Any update regarding that problem?

Comment: After reaching out to Apple technical support, we were informed that numerous components are involved in the failure case. Ideally, this issue should not arise; however, it occurs in practice. The most common point of failure identified by them is the `mediaserverd` component.

We made an optimization to the handler updates, which involved reducing the frequency of updates to the handler name displayed on the callkit UI. This adjustment has decreased the occurrence of the issue, but it has not entirely resolved the problem.

Comment: Thanks Shamim. We are also calling reportCallUpdate for each second for a call. I will try to reduce calling it. I hope it help us.